# Save chunks from database into xls

Tags: php, xls

I'm using this code by Krasimir to output data from PHP to .xls

```
function xlsBOF() {
    echo pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);
}
function xlsEOF() {
    echo pack("ss", 0x0A, 0x00);
}
function xlsWriteNumber($Row, $Col, $Value) {
    echo pack("sssss", 0x203, 14, $Row, $Col, 0x0);
    echo pack("d", $Value);
}
function xlsWriteLabel($Row, $Col, $Value) {
    $L = strlen($Value);
    echo pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $L, $Row, $Col, 0x0, $L);
    echo $Value;
} 
// prepare headers information
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"export_".date("Y-m-d").".xls\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
// start exporting
xlsBOF();
// first row 
xlsWriteLabel(0, 0, "id");
xlsWriteLabel(0, 1, "name");
xlsWriteLabel(0, 2, "email");
// second row 
xlsWriteNumber(1, 0, 230);
xlsWriteLabel(1, 1, "John");
xlsWriteLabel(1, 2, "john@yahoo.com");
// third row 
xlsWriteNumber(2, 0, 350);
xlsWriteLabel(2, 1, "Mark");
xlsWriteLabel(2, 2, "mark@yahoo.com");
// end exporting
xlsEOF();
```

It works fine for a small amount of data, but when I export from the database, for example, a large amount of data (100.000 records) I get server timeout error.

**How can I change this code so that I can write small chunks of data to the file progressivly?**

*Currently I'm using a method that works only for tab separated files or CSVs*

I'm writing chunks of 1000 rows in the .xls file. After exporting a chunk I use `window.location.href=the_script.php?offset=new_offset` to call the script for the next offset, and open the file again and append the next 1000 rows.

The problem with this method is that Excel outputs the warning *The file format and the extension don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust the source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?*

***How can I achieve something similar for the script above?***

Comment: You'll have problems with 100,000 records anyway, because xls files only allow 65,536 records in a worksheet.... if you need to handle large volumes of data, then use CSV.... but make sure that the file extension is .csv to avoid MS Excel giving you that warning when you open the file

Answer (score 1):

Increase the [time limit for PHP scripts](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: It would be a temporary solution but as the amount of data to be exported increases the time limit would increase as well, so I'll have to continue to increase it as the database grows. Also from what I know a large time limit is a vulnerability

Comment: That's true, but the access to this export functionality can be easily restricted to specific users or IP ranges... it is nothing that needs to be available to the open public.

Comment: This isn't even a valid solution anyway..... you can't export more than 65,536 records to a BIFF-format .xls file unless you split them across multiple worksheets..... that's a limitation of MS Excel and the BIFF format